# WebStorm latest 2019.3 and Angular 9. getting Cannot find module errors

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

After upgrading to Angular 9, I keep getting errors in TypeScript error console... but no errors exist when i run tsc in command line
Package Version.

[image]

my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "paths": {
      "sax": [
        "node_modules/sax"
      ],
      "timers": [
        "node_modules/timers"
      ],
      "stream": [
        "node_modules/stream"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "tmp/**/",
    "tmp/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Sean

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, had original tsconfig.json

```
"baseUrl": "./",
```

and overriden with tsconfig.app.json INSIDE ./src dir:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
```

so the tsconfig.app.json should have overridden the original but seems that WebStorm was going back and fourth (defintely a bug) so fixed it by modifying the original tsconfig.json to

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
```

so now both tsconfig in root and tsconfig.app in './src' will point to src

```
"baseUrl": "./src", in root tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": "./", in ./src/tsconfig.app.json
```

and now all is good... 
So WebStorm is getting confused and not using the LAST one which it should.

hoep it helps someone,

Sean.